# Explain the output of the given code

Tags: c

In the below code, variable i has been declared globally as well as locally in the *for* loop . Due to high precedence of local variable, i will be initialized with the value 10 . But in the first occurrence of the loop, due to i++in the for loop, value of i will become 11, so should it not exit the loop after the first instance only?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
     int i=10;
     printf(" %d",i);
     i++;
}
return 0;
```

}

P.S: The answer is 10 10 10 10 10

Comment: in cases like that it's worth to look at produced assembly code, my guess is that in this case "for" loop is unrolled to 5 calls of printf()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precedence is not just about initialization.  The variable `i` inside the loop body is a *different variable* from the one outside.  It "shadows" the outer `i`, making it inaccessible in the loop body.

The loop control statement is outside the loop body.  Its `i` is the outer `i`, and nothing done to the inner `i` has any effect on it, so it starts at 0 and counts up to 5.  At each loop iteration, the inner `i` is re-initialized to 10, and that's the one that gets printed.

Comment: So just to be clear, the i used in the for loop is actually the i declared before it

Comment: The `i` used in the loop control statement is the one declared before it, yes.

Comment: Simple rule for that: the curly braces matter. the loop control statements are outside of these, so they use the `i` available in the outer block.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it always prints is because the inner `i` [*shadows*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the outer `i`. For the same reason the `i++;` inside the loop increments the inner `i`, not the `i` that's used as the `for` loop counter.

But the `i` that controls the loop gets incremented *after* the scope of the inner `i` is over and has no relation to `i++;` done inside the loop. It's completely independent of the inner `i` and thus the loop runs 5 times.

GCC provides an option to warn about such shadowing: [`-Wshadow`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yet another answer because there is one aspect missing so far. If you change your code slightly:

```
#include<stdio.h>     
int main(){
int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
     static int i=10;
     printf(" %d",i);
     i++;
}
return 0;
}
```

You will get a more "expected" result:

> 10 11 12 13 14

A variable inside a block stops to exist after the block (read: pair of curly braces) is left (and it is left here after every step to execute the control statements of `for`) ... so with your original code, you get a new *inner `i`* each time. Declaring the inner `i` `static` still doesn't change the scope (it is only visible inside the loop body), but makes the variable *survive* and still be available when the same block is entered again.

Comment: If i am correct, this actually means that the variable inside the loop will remember the previous value of i and in each iteration of the loop the variable will be given the previous value(incremented value).

Comment: Technically, it means the variable *lifetime* of the inner `i` is not limited by its *scope*. Without the `static`, you get a *new* variable everytime the block is entered (and therefore, it is initialized every time).

Answer (score 0):

Yes the answer is correct.

As loop iterates `5` times and for every iteration `i` inside loop is set to `10` and outer one is overshadowed by inner one. After `i=10`  its value is printed therefore `5` times `10` is output.